# TypeOf object not detecting label and textbox in excel vba userforms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Problem**

I have a function whereby it detect an object and behave accordingly. But whenever a label object or textbox object, it is not detecting those as label and textbox and thus skipping the `if` conditions. By the way all objects are from a userform. The strange thing is, it is able to detect combobox objects and execute `if` conditions correctly

**My Codes**

```
Public Function enterObjectsValue(ByVal uiObject As Object)
If TypeOf uiObject Is Label Then
    Cells(DeviceSheetLastEmptyCell, headerColumn).Value = uiObject.Caption
End If

If TypeOf uiObject Is TextBox Or TypeOf uiObject Is ComboBox Then
    Cells(DeviceSheetLastEmptyCell, headerColumn).Value = uiObject.Value
End If
End Function
```

I call the above function as stated below

```
Call enterObjectsValue(mainPage.customerGroup)
```

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Label has the Text property, not Caption, might have something to do with it.  Same story for TextBox, Text not Value.  Watch out for On Error swallowing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use msforms.TextBox etc.

```
Public Function enterObjectsValue(ByVal uiObject As Object)
    If TypeOf uiObject Is msforms.Label Then
       'Cells(DeviceSheetLastEmptyCell, headerColumn).Value = uiObject.Caption
        Debug.Print uiObject.Caption
    End If

    If TypeOf uiObject Is msforms.TextBox Or TypeOf uiObject Is msforms.ComboBox Then
       'Cells(DeviceSheetLastEmptyCell, headerColumn).Value = uiObject.Value
        Debug.Print uiObject.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Storax. After gave `msforms.label`, `msforms.TextBox` and `msforms.ComboBox`, everything works fine.